# How to catch Exceptions on a JAX-WS web service without forwarding them to the client

Tags: java, jax-ws

I am working on a Java Web Service (SOAP) and I make use of Exception handling. Some of the operations may throw IOExceptions. Despite the fact that I handle them with try-catch statements, they are still sent back to the client. How can I continue the execution of the Service without sending the Exception back to the client?

For example I have the following piece of code

```
synchronized public int parseDataModelFromDatabase(Connection con, Logger webAppLog) {
    FileWriter fStream;
    BufferedWriter out;
    Connection dbCon;
    Statement st;
    this.data_model = null;
    File f = new File(this.OUTPUT_DIR + "/" + this.data_model_file);
    if(f.exists()) {
        f.delete();
    }
    try {
        f.createNewFile();
    }catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println("ItemSimilarityModel.parseDataModelFromDatabase(): Failed to create output file: "
                + e.getMessage());
        webAppLog.error("ItemSimilarityModel.parseDataModelFromDatabase() threw an IOException when attempted to create new data file: ", e);
        return -1;
    }
    if(!f.exists()) {
        return -2;
    }
    try {
        fStream = new FileWriter(this.OUTPUT_DIR + "/" + this.data_model_file);
        out = new BufferedWriter(fStream);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        System.err.println("ItemSimilarityModel.parseDataModelFromDatabase(): Failed to open output file: "
                + e.getMessage());
        webAppLog.error("ItemSimilarityModel.parseDataModelFromDatabase(): Failed to open output data file: ", e);
        return -3;
    }

    String selectStr = "SELECT * FROM " + this.dbTableUserPrefs;
    try {
        dbCon = (Connection) con;
        if(dbCon != null && dbCon.isValid(0) == true) {
            st = (Statement) dbCon.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(selectStr);
            while(rs.next()) {
                out.write(rs.getString(1) + "," + rs.getString(2) + "," +
                        rs.getString(3) + "," + rs.getString(4) + "\n");
            }
            out.close();
            dbCon.close();
        }
    }catch(SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("ItemSimilarityModel.parseDataModelFromDatabase(): SQL Exception occured: "
                + e.getMessage());
        webAppLog.error("ItemSimilarityModel.parseDataModelFromDatabase(): SQLException thrown on writing to the data model file.", e);
        return -7;
    }catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println("ItemSimilarityModel.parseDataModelFromDatabase(): IO Exception occured: "
                + e.getMessage());
        webAppLog.error("ItemSimilarityModel.parseDataModelFromDatabase(): IOException thrown on writing to the data model file.", e);
        return -8;
    }
    try {
        if(f != null && f.isFile() == true && f.exists() == true)
            this.data_model = new FileDataModel(f);
    }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println("ItemSimilarityModel.parseDataModelFromDatabase(): FileNotFoundException message: "
                + e.getMessage());
        webAppLog.error("ItemSimilarityModel.parseDataModelFromDatabase(): FileNotFoundException thrown on parsing the data model file.", e);
        return -5;
    }catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println("ItemSimilarityModel.parseDataModelFromDatabase(): IOException message: "
                + e.getMessage());
        webAppLog.error("ItemSimilarityModel.parseDataModelFromDatabase(): IOException thrown on parsing the data model file.", e);
        return -6;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This function is called by the following function which is part of the Web Service API:

```
public int ReloadRecommendationModel(@WebParam(name = "username") String uname, @WebParam(name = "password") String pass) {
    System.out.println("EngineModule.ReloadRecommendationModel called.");
    if(uname.equals(this.cap_recommender_uname) == false || pass.equals(this.cap_recommender_pass) == false) {
        return -1;
    }
    DataSource ds_preferences = null;
    DataSource ds_similarities = null;
    Connection con_preferences;
    Connection con_similarities;
    try {
        Context initContext = new InitialContext();
        Context envContext = (Context) initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
        ds_preferences = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/user_history");
        ds_similarities = (DataSource) envContext.lookup("jdbc/similarity_model");
    }catch(NamingException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        webAppLog.error("EngineModule.ReloadRecommendationModel(): Error occured while obtaining context.", e);
    }
    int val = 0;
    try {
        if(ds_preferences != null && ds_similarities != null) {
            con_preferences = (Connection) ds_preferences.getConnection();
            con_similarities = (Connection) ds_similarities.getConnection();
            synchronized(SingletonItemSimilarityModel.getModel()) {
                val = (SingletonItemSimilarityModel.getModel()).parseDataModelFromDatabase(con_preferences, webAppLog);
                if(val != 0) {
                    webAppLog.error("EngineModule.ReloadRecommendationModel(): parseDataModelFromDatabase() returned: " + val + ".");
                    return 0;
                }
                val = (SingletonItemSimilarityModel.getModel()).parseSimilarityModelFromDatabase(con_similarities, webAppLog);
                if(val != 0) {
                    webAppLog.error("EngineModule.ReloadRecommendationModel(): parseSimilarityModelFromDatabase() returned: " + val + ".");
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        }
        webAppLog.info("EngineModule.ReloadRecommendationModel(): Reload operation of data-model completed with return code: " + val + ".");
    }catch(SQLException e) {
        System.err.println("EngineModule.ReloadRecommendationModel(): Error occured while attempting to connect to Recommender data-source: " +
                 e.getMessage());
        webAppLog.error("EngineModule.ReloadRecommendationModel(): Error occured while attempting to connect to Recommender data-source.", e);
    }
    return val;
}
```

The part that may throw an Exception is the following:

```
try {
    if(f != null && f.isFile() == true && f.exists() == true)
        this.data_model = new FileDataModel(f);
}catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("ItemSimilarityModel.parseDataModelFromDatabase(): FileNotFoundException message: "
            + e.getMessage());
    webAppLog.error("ItemSimilarityModel.parseDataModelFromDatabase(): FileNotFoundException thrown on parsing the data model file.", e);
    return -5;
}catch(IOException e) {
    System.err.println("ItemSimilarityModel.parseDataModelFromDatabase(): IOException message: "
            + e.getMessage());
    webAppLog.error("ItemSimilarityModel.parseDataModelFromDatabase(): IOException thrown on parsing the data model file.", e);
    return -6;
}
```

How can I make sure that the execution will not stop and the Exception is not seen from the Client?

Thank you,
Nick

Comment: Show small example of code throwing exception and list the exception sent to the client.  You may not catch what you think you catch.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I edited the post, so you can get more information.

Comment: None of these functions declares that it throws an IOException, so I think it's likely that either a) your exception is being thown from somewhere else in the code or b) it isn't an IOException that is being thrown back to the client. Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: @DaveHowes The last code quote features a try-catch block which throws either a FileNotFoundException or an IOException. I want to handle properly the FileNotFoundException and I do not want to be forwarded to the client.

Comment: And the stacktrace of the IOException?

Comment: The last code quote CATCHES FileNotFoundException and IOException and returns a negative integer - it doesn't throw anything as far as I can see. If the code inside the try/catch block throws a FileNotFoundException, this code will return -5, if it throws an IOException it'll return -6. In neither case will the Exception escape from the try catch block

Answer (score 0):

Consider wrapping your code in a `try-catch(Throwable e)`.  This should catch everything.